# Pause and Full Screen not working in Chrome 30 on Android 4.2.1

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I am using the default browser controls on mobile. The pause and full screen work fine in HTML5 Video Player but once I add in videojs they are not clickable in Chrome 30 on Android 4.2.1. I am avoiding the custom controls on mobile as I understand they are turned off by default due to stability issues. I have tried turning them on in mobile, but that introduces more issues across multiple mobile browsers.

Anyone else run into this? I'm thinking I may need to hack in the custom controls just for Chrome but I'd prefer not to have to do that.